# Home page alias

Tags: kentico

We have a Kentico v9.0 project where the Content Tree is established as follows (greatly simplified as it's a 4000+ page website).

- Root

  - Home

    - Products
    - About Us
    - News
    - Contact Us

We want the Home page to be available from the root of the domain name  **http://domain-name.com/** rather than **http://domain-name.com/home**

Our SEO team want the level 1 pages aliased like so:

- /products
- /about-us
- /news
- /contact-us

Rather than:

- /home/products
- /home/about-us
- /home/news
- /home/contact-us

I've attempted to follow the steps outlined in this old v7.0 article https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/set-a-domain-name-to-be-a-default-alias-path-in-url

However I have run into a problem at Step 4. When I tried to rename my **Alias Path** for the Home page to just **/** the CMS automatically sets the Alias Path to **-**. I assume this is because the forward slash is considered an invalid character.

Can someone please advise if this method is still supported in v9.0 and if so how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentico automatically add all previous aliases if you have a structure like this. In

> CMS_Tree table -> NodeAliasPath column

you can actually see how the whole path looks like. This path is updated whenever you update/create node alias which is part of the structure.

In case you wan't to omit the "Home" completely you have 3 options:

1) Remove the "Home" page and move all pages directly under the root

2) Use custom url path by configuring the **Path or pattern** property:

[image: Path or pattern property]

3) Create page alias which also uses the custom path or pattern:

[image: Page alias with custom path]

If you want to ensure that a page is accessible only by 1 url, you can enable the **Settings -> URLs and SEO -> Redirect page aliases to main URL**

Note: You could also create an IIS rewrite rule, but this wouldn't change how the URLs are rendered on your pages and it wouldn't probably be a good idea to rely on rewrite for just this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. Option 1 may not work for us as there will be some content on the Home page which is a Custom page type. Option 2 looks quite plausible, I'll see how that works because I could catch the event in code and create these for the CMS User and a large number of pages are created by the Integration Bus so I'm already able to set these programatically. Option 3... hmm... I'll have a look.

Comment: Yeah, you could definitelly use global events to automatically fill the Path or Pattern property (it's "DocumentUrlPath" column in CMS_Document), but it also depends on the scenario. You would probably need to create some script to do this on existing pages as well. If that is the case, you might as well programatically move all pages one level up and remove the "Home" page all together :)

Comment: I followed Option 2 and the CMS_Tree table still has NodeAliasPath as /Home/About-Us it does serve the page from /About-Us but now I'm concerned that in my Links etc that the NodeAliasPath will be /Home/About-Us. For example if I use a repeater and get a list of NodeAliasPaths for menu that they will be /Home/***

Comment: Yeah, the NodeAliasPath will still work (see the note in my answer). It depends on how exactly you are generating links. If you are using NodeAliasPath to create links you need to change this to DocumentUrlPath. E.g. instead of using <%# Eval("NodeAliasPath") %> use <%# Eval("DocumentUrlPath") %> In this case it might be also a good idea to check if the DocumentUrlPath is empty or not. If it is - use NodeAliasPath instead as it may happen that it is not filled for some documents. Otherwise you can use NodeAliasPath.

Comment: Awesome advice Richard thank you. Most of our link generating transformations are using <%# Eval("NodeAliasPath") %>  I try this and report back and issues. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm going to go with a variation to Option 1 in your answer above. Leave the Home Page and move all Level 1 pages under the Root. Similar to the content tree shown in Kentico's demo. https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9Tutorial/Managing+content+-+The+basics?preview=/60884211/60884212/pages_application.png

Comment: Option 2 was plausible but programatically setting the DocumentUrlPath via a Global Event handler seemed a bit too excessive. Especially given the depth of pages on this website, I would need to recursively traverse a long way back up the tree to concatenate all of the NodeAliasPath's.

Answer (score 2):

you can do an update to the db to add the DocumentURLPath. This will write over any url paths that may have been entered, but it remove /home from the paths.

```
update cms_document set DocumentURLPath = Replace(Replace(DocumentNamePath,' ','-'),'/home','')
```

You could also try doing a mass move. In Pages select the home page & click Listing (top of content tree) that will list all of the pages in the home page. Then you could select all of them and move them to the root. Moving the inner pages shouldnt affect the template of the home page at all. If you are using a repeater on the home page to look at content in the inner pages, you can just re-point the path in the repeater.

Comment: Flattening out the top Level of the Content Tree would work, moving the Level 1 pages to the Root alongside Home. The only minor issue with that would be Breadcrumb / Nav but we can probably handle that.

Comment: I have bumped this to Kentico Support to see what they think.

Comment: I've decided to flatten out the site structure at the top level. Kentico Support provide advice on getting the Home page to serve from / but didn't suggest any option to ensure the NodeAliasPath's of the Child pages were /contact-us they would still have been /home/contact-us. I entertained programatically setting them but have taken the simplest approach on the basis that it's the standard "out of the box" solution. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt follow that article for a V9 site. Instead Go to Settings > Content. Under website content > make Default Alias Path: /home

Comment: Thank you. That will definately ensure that the domain name serves the Home page but does not address the Alias issues for the remaining pages. So http://domain-name.com/ would serve the home page. However /contact-us would not work. We would need to manually set an alias on each of our 4000+ pages to remove the /home/

Comment: Try it out. I was able to do this for a test site. I created a page /home and added 2 pages under it. After setting the default alias path to /home I could go to localhost/test1 (which was located in /home/test1) without modifying any other settings.

Comment: Ok I'll try. I might be carrying some v7.0 baggage with me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this didn't work for me. I set the Default Alias Path to /Home and that opens the Home page from localhost/ but I get a 404 for localhost/contact-us

Comment: does contact us have a custom path or pattern entered into the URL Alias or is that field blank?

Comment: It has Page alias: Contact-Us   It has Use custom URL path: ticked   It has Path type:   Standard URL or wildcard     And the Path or Pattern: <empty>    No additional Page Aliases

Comment: If I set Path or pattern to contact-us then it works. But I'm not sure I can expect the CMS User to do this manually on 4000+ pages. But I would be able to handle this in a event handler and set it via the API.

Comment: Yea I just tested a sql query to do a mass update & provided in a below answer. My initial answer wouldnt have worked, I forget Kentico saves the past urls and I moved the test files under home from the root and the alias from the root had been generated.